# Powershell add new items to Enum list

Tags: powershell

I have a script with an enum list i use so I want to enter new values through my form I made but can't find a command for that...

i have my new item as $newitem and my enum list randomfood (its about food^^)

Something like `enum.additem = $newitem`

Is there something like this?

Comment: Enums aren't really meant to be used like updatable arrays.  Maybe a hashtable would be more suitable.

Comment: @boxdog my script is based on these enums it would really help... :(

Comment: I recommend to read this [Hey, Scripting Guy!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/08/27/working-with-enums-in-powershell-5/) blog post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enum` are not generally supposed to add and remove elements.

Instead you could use `System.Collections.ArrayList` or `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` they both support **Add** and **Remove** methods.

Comment: thanks that would work to but I just thought i can do all that in c# ^^ so i^ll ty there ;)